# When using WHERE with oledb I get "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Tags: vb.net, csv, oledb, oledbcommand

I get the error "No value given for one or more required parameters." at the .Fill

```vb
  Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter_
        ("SELECT * FROM [" & FileName & _
        "] WHERE Column_Name <> '-1' AND Column_Name <> '-2'", conn)
    da.Fill(dtnew)
```

This works:

```vb
  Dim da As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" _
        & FileName & "]", conn)
    da.Fill(dtnew)
```

I've added line breaks for clarity.

My two thoughts were:

1) Not possible when using OleBb with a .csv, but I thought I have seen people be successful elsewhere.

2) My formatting is wrong in the query. Nothing I have found on here or Google gives a standard format. Most places I have looked suggest something like []'s around columnname. I have tried brackets all over the place with no luck except new errors.

Comment: When you fill `dtnew` in the working example, look at the name of the columns in the debugger.

Comment: @LarsTech Very good sir. I was using the column names from the SQL table that this datatable was going be merged with.

Comment: The error stated is very generic - often there is just a syntax error in the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to LarsTech I realized that the column names in the .csv/.xlsx were not the same as the ones in the SQL database. The fix was simple I just had to change the column name to [ID #].